# How to send an email on Postal using an email address from the database Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, controller, postal

I've currently implemented [Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/) and I'm using that to send emails on my MVC application. The problem I'm having is that I want to retrieve an email address from my database, instead of hard-coding the address I want to send the email to.

So to give a bit of context on where I'd like to implement this. After I create my Order, I want to send an email address to the Hospital that is linked to that order.

This is what I have tried, but it throws an exception on this line `email.To = order.Hospital.Email;` - It does work if I hard code the email address like, for example , `email.To = "hospital@hospital.com".`

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   HealthHabitat.dll but was not handled in user code

I've included it in my `Create POST method` so that it triggers once the model has been saved.

The email address **is** saved as a **string** in my Hospital Model.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "OrderID,HospitalID,StaffID,Date,Time,Expected_Date")] Order order)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        order.StaffID = 5;
        db.Orders.Add(order);
        db.SaveChanges();
        dynamic email = new Email("Example");
        email.To = order.Hospital.Email; // this is where you set the email you are sending to. 
        email.Send();
        Success(string.Format("<i class='fa fa-plus-circle'></i> Please Add your Items!", order.OrderID), true);
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = order.OrderID });
    }


    ViewBag.HospitalID = new SelectList(db.Hospitals, "HospitalID", "Name", order.HospitalID);
    Danger("<i class='fa fa-warning'></i> Error!", true);
    return View(order);
}
```

Does any one have a solution to this? I'll greatly appreciate it and thanks in advance!

If any additional information is needed, please let me know and I'll add it to the question.

**Hospital Model:**

```
public class Hospital
{
    public int HospitalID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Province { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Phone_Number { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: What does your model look like?

Comment: @StuartL Edited the Question with the Model.

Comment: What do you mean by bombs out? Does it throw an exception? What exception is?

Comment: @Vova NullReferenceException

Comment: Does `Email` actually contain any data at the point where you are trying to access it? The error suggests not. In your view, are you including the properties in your `Hospital` class in the form?

Comment: This just mean that `Hospital` property of an `order` is null

Comment: @StuartL The problem is that the email address is in the Hospital table. So how would I get it from that table based on the Hospital that is selected upon creation of an Order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
order.StaffID = 5;
db.Orders.Add(order);
db.SaveChanges();

//select hospital from database.
Hospital hospital = db.Hospitals.First(h => h.HospitalId == order.HospitalId);

dynamic email = new Email("Example");
email.To = hospital.Email; // this is where you set the email you are sending to. 
email.Send();
```

Comment: Surely you mean `h.Id == order.HospitalId` instead of `h.Id = order.HospitalId`

Comment: It has a problem with `h => h.Id` says that it doesn't exist? Should I be declaring something somewhere? or passing a variable?

Comment: @mustang00, 'h => h.HospitalID' instead of 'h => h.Id'.

Comment: This works, taking into account both Stuart and Hiren's fixes.